# How to calculate the probability of a customer having to wait more than 5min in the queue?

Tags: queue, probability, anylogic

I have to calculate the probability of a customer waiting more than 5 min in the queue in anylogic. I've already implemented the timemeasureend and-start block, but I have seriously no clue how to compute the probability of a customer waiting longer than 5min? What do I need to write where? Help is highly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two objects in a process modelling library: **TimeMeasureStart** and **TimeMeasureEnd**. You can put those around a queue and record the time for each entity after they exit the queue. Save that time to a Statistics object and from there your probability if waiting more that 5 mins should be (no of samples over 5 mins)/(total number of entities). Also, make sure that your model time unit is set to *minute* to make it easier.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm aware of the timemeasurestart and timemeasureend block and have already contributed the average time in the queue. But I'm not quiet sure how I can contribute the number of agents over 5 mins. I mean, where am I supposed to generate this from and how?

Comment: and I have already depict the data from the average number in queue in a histogram

Comment: Each **TimeMeasureEnd** object has a *dataset* property. In there is a list of *x,y* pairs where *x* is an entry time into **TimeMeasureStart** and *y* is an exit time through **TimeMeasureEnd**. So at any point, it is possible to go through that dataset, calculate the difference *y - x* and count the ones <= 5 mins. You can see more [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/timemeasureend.html).